# How to stabilize a video with FAST algorithm?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to opencv and I'm trying to stabilize a video with FAST algorithm( http://www.edwardrosten.com/work/fast.html ).
I have wrote some code but the result is not very good , how can i improve the video stabilization?
this is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

Mat frame, frame_edg, prev_frame,warped;
Mat T,last_T;
vector<KeyPoint> corners,prev_corners;
vector<Point2f> corners2f,prev_corners2f;
int key = 0;

VideoCapture cap("video.mp4");//inizializzo l'oggetto VideoCapture con il mio video

if (!cap.isOpened()) {//controllo se è stato aperto
    cout<<"Impossbile aprire il video"<<endl;
    return -1;
}
double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);//ricavo i frame per secondo
cout<<"Frame per secondo: "<<fps<<endl;

namedWindow("Sequenza Originale",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);//creo una finestra auto-dimensionante
namedWindow("Sequenza in grigio",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("Warped");

while (key!=27) {

    cap >> frame;
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(frame, frame);
    vector <Point2f> prev_corners2, cur_corners2;
    vector <uchar> status;
    vector <float> err;


    imshow("Sequenza Originale", frame);
    if (!prev_frame.empty())
    {
        FAST(frame, corners, 5);//corner detection
        FAST(prev_frame, prev_corners, 5);//corner detection
        KeyPoint::convert(corners, corners2f);
        KeyPoint::convert(prev_corners, prev_corners2f);
        calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_frame, frame, prev_corners2f, corners2f, status, err);//matching
        // weed out bad matches
        for(size_t i=0; i < status.size(); i++) {
            if(status[i]) {
                prev_corners2.push_back(prev_corners2f[i]);
                cur_corners2.push_back(corners2f[i]);
            }
        }
        T=estimateRigidTransform(cur_corners2, prev_corners2, false);
        // in rare cases no transform is found. We'll just use the last known good transform.
        if(T.data == NULL) {
            last_T.copyTo(T);
        }

        T.copyTo(last_T);
        warpAffine(frame, warped, T, Size(frame.cols,frame.rows));
        imshow("Warped", warped);
        prev_frame = frame.clone();
    }
    if(prev_frame.empty())
    {
        prev_frame = frame.clone();
    }
    key = waitKey(30);

}
destroyAllWindows();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using features your result may be not very stable, since features may appear and disappear, causing shaking. You may want to try approaches that are based on finding transformation that minimizes intensity difference between corresponding pixels from whole frames.

When I was fiddling with video stabilization I used [ESM](http://far.in.tum.de/pub/benhimane2004iros1/benhimane2004iros1.pdf) as a main tool. I am not sure if there are available implementations now,  but it is not hard to roll your own if you feel confident with jacobians and matrix operations. You can see figure 5 from the linked paper as an example - it can be used to track/stabilize planar areas rather robustly. But your frames are likely not really planar, so you'll have to implement some kind of outlier rejection. You also have to figure out how will you compare frames - last-with-previous, or last-with-first. I was working on stabilization for some sort of timelapse videos, so used the latter approach, but for real videos you will probably use former, since it allows drift of camera position over time.